# Can we use pressure analogy to understand inflation?

Tags: cosmology, pressure, cosmological-inflation

Classically, the expansion of a gas in a container requires the gas to apply outward pressure to the walls of the container. Is it also true for the Universe during inflation? How did the inflation drive the expansion of Universe? I think this analogy is poor because it's not the expansion of a gas in a container. Nothing applies an outward pressure of the "walls" of the Universe rather it is the space that expands.

Answer (score 1):

During inflation the universe was expanding de Sitter like which means it expanded exponentially. This requires repulsive gravity due to the inflaton field and implies a negative Friedmann term $\rho + 3p$ (then the the second derivative of the scale factor has a positive constant value as required). Hence the pressure $p$ must be negative because during inflation the matter density $\rho$ is zero.

It's clear from this that we can't use the gas analogy to explain inflation.  Simply said while gas exerting positive pressure *pushes* negative pressure *pulls*. Think of a stretched rubberband.

How do we explain negative pressure? Withdrawing a piston containing vacuum energy creates an increase of internal energy $dU = \rho_{vac} dV$. Now because of the conservation of energy this increase must according to thermodynamics equal the work done by the pressure of the vacuum $-p_{vac}dV$. So we get the equation of state $p_{vac} = -\rho_{vac}$ and as the vacuum density is positive a negative vacuum pressure. The point here is that in contrast to gas the vacuum energy density is constant while the piston is withdrawn. So the work done to inflate the universe is supplied by the vacuum energy "for free".

Comment: What is repulsive gravity in Einstein's theory? In what sense?

Comment: Einstein introduced the cosmological constant $\Lambda$. This vacuum energy is associated with.

Comment: Einstein introduced the cosmological constant $\Lambda$. This vacuum energy is associated with negative pressure which  causes repulsive gravity. The inflaton field is different as it decays to matter but like the cc has negative pressure too.

Comment: @ttim - This is a ridiculous analogy.  Yes, a piston pulling out of a cylinder creates negative pressure *differential* with respect to the air outside the engine and so air flows into the cylinder.  The piston chamber of the world's most powerful engine still has an absolute, positive pressure with respect to the universe.  So how does the **universe** generate a negative pressure?

Comment: @ttime - and how is the matter density $\rho$ zero?  How does this have an analog in real science?

Comment: @Donald Airey "So how does the universe generate a negative pressure?" It follows from the equation of state I mentioned. Simply said with gas in the piston chamber and outside vacuum the positive pressure will increase the volume. Whereas with vacuum inside work has to be done like stretching a spring and this is due to negative pressure.

Comment: "how is the matter density ρ zero?" Matter is created at the end of inflation when the inflaton field decays, google "reheating".

Comment: If Fermions and Bosons could evaporate into some undiscovered field, or form spontaneously from those fields, why haven't we seen a reaction like that yet? Every experiment out of LHC indicates that the Standard Model is correct and complete. So I'll ask again, is there any real science with a viable theoretical foundation behind this idea of zero matter density?

Comment: Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_(cosmology)#Reheating . The temperature here was in the Planck regime and hence many orders above the LHC provides. There might be a misunderstanding. The inflaton field is a scalar field, so it is homogeneous, means no particles. Instead its energy decayed into particles during reheating.

Comment: @timm - "*Because the nature of the inflation is not known, this process is still poorly understood*",... meaning it's made up out of whole cloth.  My point is, you don't just go making Standard Model particles out of nothing.  The process for creating and destroying SM particles is well understood and has been tested and validated with innumerable experiments on the worlds largest, most expensive laboratory.  I would like to understand what theoretical foundation you have for creating a Fermion or Boson from a field that is outside of known fields of SM.

Comment: @Donald Airey For details see 7 Reheating and High-Energy Physics models and 8 Observational implications and signatures of reheating in https://wwwmpa.mpa-garching.mpg.de/~komatsu/lecturenotes/Kaloian_Lozanov_on_Reheating.pdf . Notice there are lots of inflationary models which agree that in general reheating did happen. As far as I can the details are under investigation though. I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: It isn't a case of ''must'' be conserved. This wholly depends on the equation of state which can be diabatic and adiabatic.

Comment: @Donald I cannot speak for the OP but there are perfectly acceptable particle creation models in strong gravitational fields which require no inflation.

Comment: @timm - I don't think you understood my question.  I'm asking for **real science**, not science fiction built on the hypothesis of even more outrageous science fiction.  At some point you jokers need to be accountable to the real universe, so  I'm asking for one experiment that falsifies or validates your belief in an extension to the Standard Model.  I think there's more than enough evidence out of LHC for a reasonable scientist to falsify the SUSY hypothesis, but you keep on redrawing the line like a Bugs Bunny cartoon.